# Cannot Click Any Links because an element covering them in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem when making a wordpress theme ([you can check out on this link](http://dev.galerigadget.com/news/)) like some links cannot clickable because being blocked by header element such as screenshot below:
[image: cannot clickable]

**style.css**

```
#content{
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.menu {
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   text-align: center;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 22px;
   background-image: url('img/logo.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 18% 21%;
   background-position: top center;
   background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

How I can fix it? Thanks before!

Comment: `pointer-events:none` ??

Comment: @paulie_D Which line I should input these code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you've provided, the issue lies with the positioning of the .menu.  When you set top, right, bottom, or left to 0, essentially, you are using css to tell the html element 'touch this side'.  When you set all four to 0, you're telling the element to touch all 4 sides and therefore cover the entire page. Since the menu is covering the entire page, when you hover on the page, you're hovering over the menu and nothing else.

Try taking away bottom: 0; on the .menu, and setting a height for it.  You'll also have to change the background size to accommodate the new menu size.

Looking at the actual site, there's more issues than that and this alone won't solve it.  It seems like the div with the classes "collapse navbar-collapse" is doing something similar so you're going to have to edit that too.

Hope that helps!